# json_decode doesn't work without utf8_encode

Tags: php, t-sql, json, utf8-decode

I get a utf8-json-String from java as a post variable into my php file.

my php header ist set as charset=utf-8, the html charset=utf-8 and the php file is utf8 without BOM.

I try to write the json data into a TSQL Database.

If I do

```
$jsonfile = $_POST['jsonfile'];
$jsonfile = utf8_decode($jsonfile); 
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile);
foreach($jsonarray as $value)   {
// write in database
}
```

all the data is written into my database. Unfortunatelly the charset deletes german chars like ß (ß).

if i do only

```
$jsonfile = $_POST['jsonfile'];
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile);
foreach($jsonarray as $value)   {
// write in database
}
```

the php fails to run through the array.

Comment: Did you set the right charset on the DB fields too?

Comment: If I copy and paste the json string into the php file and reference it to $jsonfile the json_decode without utf8_decode works well. Everything is written into the database. So I query wether it is because of the DB charset

Answer (score 0):

(Im assuming you are also writing the Java client.)

Send the POST request as `Content-type: application/json` and the JSON as the payload of the request rather than sending it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with a hunk of JSON in a form field.

You can read the full contents of the payload in PHP with `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

Comment: No, the JSON comes from another source. I can view the JSON String how it comes. If I copy and paste it into the code it works so there are maybe special charakters I have to filter.